# CoreGraphics code isn't making a hollow shape, as expected

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-graphics

This is the code I have:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGColorRef redColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;

CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
    CGRect inside = CGRectMake(120, 120, 60, 60);



CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, redColor);
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);
CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceOut);
CGContextFillRect(context, inside);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

I'm trying to make the inside shape hollow, but instead it's giving me a red square (as expecetd) with a black square in the middle, when the UIView in the background is white.

Any ideas on how to make the shape transparent here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few ways you can fill your rectangle with a hollow inner rectangle.  One way is to create a path that contains both rectangles, and fill it using the [even-odd rule](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF106).

```
CGContextRef gc = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextBeginPath(gc);
CGContextAddRect(gc, CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100));
CGContextAddRect(gc, CGRectMake(120, 120, 60, 60));
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(gc, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
CGContextEOFillPath(gc);
```